# Trying to apply "multiple Image cropbox in a single page", need to change the id with .js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the cropbox.js javascript function to crop images. I need to use the cropbox in a page at 2/more times. First one is working correctly, but second/others is not, because of the "id" repeating one more times.. How can i call the input id differently? See my code below.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
        var options =
        {
            imageBox: '.imageBox',
            thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
            spinner: '.spinner',
            imgSrc: 'avatar.png'
        }
        var cropper;
        document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                options.imgSrc = e.target.result;
                cropper = new cropbox(options);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            this.files = [];
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var img = cropper.getDataURL()
            document.querySelector('.cropped').innerHTML += '<img src="'+img+'">';
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomIn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomIn();
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomOut').addEventListener('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomOut();
        })
    };
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 'use strict';
var cropbox = function(options){
    var el = document.querySelector(options.imageBox),
    obj =
    {
        state : {},
        ratio : 1,
        options : options,
        imageBox : el,
        thumbBox : el.querySelector(options.thumbBox),
        spinner : el.querySelector(options.spinner),
        image : new Image(),
        getDataURL: function ()
        {
            var width = this.thumbBox.clientWidth,
                height = this.thumbBox.clientHeight,
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                dim = el.style.backgroundPosition.split(' '),
                size = el.style.backgroundSize.split(' '),
                dx = parseInt(dim[0]) - el.clientWidth/2 + width/2,
                dy = parseInt(dim[1]) - el.clientHeight/2 + height/2,
                dw = parseInt(size[0]),
                dh = parseInt(size[1]),
                sh = parseInt(this.image.height),
                sw = parseInt(this.image.width);

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
            var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            return imageData;
        },
        getBlob: function()
        {
            var imageData = this.getDataURL();
            var b64 = imageData.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
            var binary = atob(b64);
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
            }
            return  new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
        },
        zoomIn: function ()
        {
            this.ratio*=1.1;
            setBackground();
        },
        zoomOut: function ()
        {
            this.ratio*=0.9;
            setBackground();
        }
    },
    attachEvent = function(node, event, cb)
    {
        if (node.attachEvent)
            node.attachEvent('on'+event, cb);
        else if (node.addEventListener)
            node.addEventListener(event, cb);
    },
    detachEvent = function(node, event, cb)
    {
        if(node.detachEvent) {
            node.detachEvent('on'+event, cb);
        }
        else if(node.removeEventListener) {
            node.removeEventListener(event, render);
        }
    },
    stopEvent = function (e) {
        if(window.event) e.cancelBubble = true;
        else e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    setBackground = function()
    {
        var w =  parseInt(obj.image.width)*obj.ratio;
        var h =  parseInt(obj.image.height)*obj.ratio;

        var pw = (el.clientWidth - w) / 2;
        var ph = (el.clientHeight - h) / 2;

        el.setAttribute('style',
                'background-image: url(' + obj.image.src + '); ' +
                'background-size: ' + w +'px ' + h + 'px; ' +
                'background-position: ' + pw + 'px ' + ph + 'px; ' +
                'background-repeat: no-repeat');
    },
    imgMouseDown = function(e)
    {
        stopEvent(e);

        obj.state.dragable = true;
        obj.state.mouseX = e.clientX;
        obj.state.mouseY = e.clientY;
    },
    imgMouseMove = function(e)
    {
        stopEvent(e);

        if (obj.state.dragable)
        {
            var x = e.clientX - obj.state.mouseX;
            var y = e.clientY - obj.state.mouseY;

            var bg = el.style.backgroundPosition.split(' ');

            var bgX = x + parseInt(bg[0]);
            var bgY = y + parseInt(bg[1]);

            el.style.backgroundPosition = bgX +'px ' + bgY + 'px';

            obj.state.mouseX = e.clientX;
            obj.state.mouseY = e.clientY;
        }
    },
    imgMouseUp = function(e)
    {
        stopEvent(e);
        obj.state.dragable = false;
    },
    zoomImage = function(e)
    {
        var evt=window.event || e;
        var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta;
        delta > -120 ? obj.ratio*=1.1 : obj.ratio*=0.9;
        setBackground();
    }

    obj.spinner.style.display = 'block';
    obj.image.onload = function() {
        obj.spinner.style.display = 'none';
        setBackground();

        attachEvent(el, 'mousedown', imgMouseDown);
        attachEvent(el, 'mousemove', imgMouseMove);
        attachEvent(document.body, 'mouseup', imgMouseUp);
        var mousewheel = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel';
        attachEvent(el, mousewheel, zoomImage);
    };
    obj.image.src = options.imgSrc;
    attachEvent(el, 'DOMNodeRemoved', function(){detachEvent(document.body, 'DOMNodeRemoved', imgMouseUp)});

    return obj;
};
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.cropbox {
 width:100%;
 padding:20px
}
.action {
 width: 600px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
}
.cropped>img {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.imageBox {
 position: relative;
 height: 600px;
 width: 600px;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 background: #262626;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: move;
}
.imageBox .thumbBox {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
.imageBox .spinner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 400px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

```html
<!--cropbox1-->
<div class="cropbox">
  <div class="imageBox">
    <div class="thumbBox"></div>
    <div class="spinner" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <input type="file" id="file" style="float:left; width: 250px">
    <input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="float: right">
    <input type="button" id="btnZoomIn" value="+" style="float: right">
    <input type="button" id="btnZoomOut" value="-" style="float: right">
  </div>
  <div class="cropped"> </div>
</div>


<!--cropbox2-->
<div class="cropbox" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="imageBox">
    <div class="thumbBox"></div>
    <div class="spinner" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <input type="file" id="file" style="float:left; width: 250px">
    <input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="float: right">
    <input type="button" id="btnZoomIn" value="+" style="float: right">
    <input type="button" id="btnZoomOut" value="-" style="float: right">
  </div>
  <div class="cropped"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML rules #42: one shall never have two times the same id on a single page.

Comment: Yes i know, it is only possible with different ID, but how can i do that?

Comment: use class rather than id and use document.querySelector('.class-name')

Comment: @vishnu did you achieved multiple cropping selection in single image ?